# Firebase en KOTLIN me regresa null o que no encuentra el usuario solamente en el primer inicio de sesión y el token ya expirado

Tags: firebase, kotlin, jwt

¡Buenas!

Tengo un problema con firebase en kotlin. Cuando quiero iniciar sesión después de que el token ya ha expirado, siempre me regresa un **null de que no encuentra al usuario**, pero **solo en la primer petición**. Si cierro la app y refresca el token, ya me deja iniciar sesión normal.

Tengo una clase socketManager que maneja las conexiones y toma el token guardado en el sharedPreferences. La muestro por sí sirve de algo.

Y muestro la función donde verificamos el inicio de sesión.

```
fun createConnection(context: Context, socketURL: String): Socket {
            val socket: Socket
            val options = IO.Options()
            options.transports = arrayOf("websocket")
            options.upgrade = false
            //options.query = "token=${Utils.getString(context, Config.PreferenceKey.DEVICEID)}"

            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.getIdToken(true).addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful){
                    Log.i("createConnection" , "token -> " + it.result!!.token)
                    options.query = "token=${it.result!!.token}"

                }
            }


            /**
             * This would help to ignore ssl related warnings, but should not go in production
             */
            val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
            sslContext.init(null, arrayOf<TrustManager>(object : X509TrustManager {
                @SuppressLint("TrustAllX509TrustManager")
                override fun checkClientTrusted(chain: Array<X509Certificate>, authType: String) = Unit

                @SuppressLint("TrustAllX509TrustManager")
                override fun checkServerTrusted(chain: Array<X509Certificate>, authType: String) = Unit

                override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<X509Certificate> = arrayOf()
            }), null)

            IO.setDefaultHostnameVerifier { hostname, session -> true }
            //IO.setDefaultSSLContext(sslContext)
            socket = IO.socket(socketURL, options)
            socket.connect()
            return socket
        }

        fun disconnectSocket(socket: Socket?) {
            Log.i("DISCONNECTSOCKET", "SI")
            socket?.disconnect()
            val close = socket?.close()
        }// end of disconnectSocket

    }



private fun verifyUserLogin() {
    HttpClient.retrofit = null
    mAuth!!.currentUser!!.getIdToken(true)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.i("verifyUserLogin2", "it.result!! -> " + Gson().toJson(it.result!!))
                        services.verifyUserLogin(Locale.getDefault().language.toUpperCase(), TokenObject(it.result!!.token.toString()))
                                .enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<HttpResponse<TokenObjectResult>> {
                                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<HttpResponse<TokenObjectResult>>?, response: Response<HttpResponse<TokenObjectResult>>?) {
                                        try {

                                                //Llega null y truena
                                                val resp = response!!.body() as HttpResponse<TokenObjectResult>

                                                Utils.setString(this@LoginActivity, Config.PreferenceKey.DEVICEID, it.result!!.token.toString())
                                                Utils.setString(this@LoginActivity, Config.PreferenceKey.ID, resp?.`object`!!.user!!._id!!)

                                                val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, HomeActivity::class.java)

                                                startActivity(intent)
                                                Handler().postDelayed({
                                                    pushNotificationLogin()
                                                }, 1000)

                                              //  saveTokenPushNotifications()
                                                finish()

                                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                                            DialogBottomSheets().setMessage("Hubo errores en el servidor, vuelve a intentarlo... " + e.message + "FIN DE ERROR").show(supportFragmentManager, "")
                                            e.printStackTrace()
                                            println("Error --> " + e.message)
                                        }
                                    }

                                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<HttpResponse<TokenObjectResult>>?, t: Throwable?) {
                                        Log.e("error", "autentication", t)

                                    }
                                })
                }
            }
}
```

De momento no sé porque pasa realmente eso, como que guarda el token y hace la verificación con el token expirado, cuando debería revisar si esta expirado, sacar un nuevo token valido y usar dicho token valido para hacer de nuevo la consulta del login.

Comment: El problema es que el onComplete del getIdToken se ejecuta de forma asyncronica la primera vez, entonces el socket se conecta antes de que se seteara el token. Las proxima vez que se ejecuta funciona de forma cuasi sincronica porque ya tiene el valor guardado en la cache.

Comment: Cierto, había llegado a la misma conclusion, pero realmente no sé como corregirlo o cual es la forma correcta de implementarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Yo intentaria primero realizar la llamada a firebase pidiendo el token y recien cuando lo obtengamos llamar a `createConnection` pansandole el token y armando el socket todo al mismo tiempo.

Algo asi:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.getIdToken(true).addOnCompleteListener {
    if (it.isSuccessful){
       Log.i("createConnection" , "token -> " + it.result!!.token)
       val query = "token=${it.result!!.token}"
       createConnection(....)
    }
}
```